# Setting navbar items to active onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a lot of trouble making navbar item to active on click.
I have included this navbar file to different pages but when i click on an item it doesn't change its class or its styling.
I have tried many techniques from using jquery onclick functions to add class active on click to changing changing css onclick but nothing is working. Any possible help will be highly appreciated  . Navbar code is below :

```
<div class="header" id="home">
    <div class="content white agile-info">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                        <h1><span class="fa fa-signal" aria-hidden="true"></span> Soft <label>Hr Agency</label></h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!--/.navbar-header-->
                <div class="nav navbar-nav  mr-auto" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="margin-right: -5%">

                    <nav class="link-effect-2" id="link-effect-2">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.php" class="effect-3">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="services.php" class="dropdown-toggle effect-3" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="services.php">Services 2</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="services.php">Services 3</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="codes.php">Codes</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="icons.php">Icons</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="services.php">One more separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="jobs.php" class="dropdown-toggle effect-3" data-toggle="dropdown">Jobs<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Walk-ins</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Bpo Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Teaching Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Diploma Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Tech Support</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Finance Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Part time Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Health Care</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Hospitality</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Internships</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Research Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Defence Jobs</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                                <li><a href="login.php">Recruiter Updates</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="upload.php">Upload Resume</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="codes.php">Shortcodes</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="events.php" class="effect-3">Events</a></li>

                            <li><a href="professional.php" class="effect-3">Professionals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php" class="effect-3">Contact</a></li>

                            <li  >
                              <a style="margin-top: -5%" href="login.php"> 
                                <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='login.php';" style="float: right;background: #23B684;width: 100%;color: white" class="btn btn-block"> 
                                     <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"> </i>   Login</button></a></li>

                        </ul>


                    </nav>
                </div>
                <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
                <!--/.navbar-->
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your `JS` even if it's not working so we can see what is wrong;

Comment: Are you including your `js` Files as described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)?

Comment: Sorry, I just remove my previous scripts that were not working.

Comment: yes i have included and other scripts are working fine

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should work using JQuery:

```
$('.nav .navbar-nav li a').click(function(){
$(this).addClass("active"); });
```

you have also to check what the active class is changing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is for every `<li>` item that you click, an `active` class name would be added to its list of class names. If I'm right in what I'm thinking, here's my suggestion:

HTML

```
<div class="header" id="home">
    <div class="content white agile-info">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                        <h1><span class="fa fa-signal" aria-hidden="true"></span> Soft <label>Hr Agency</label></h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!--/.navbar-header-->
                <div class="nav navbar-nav  mr-auto" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="margin-right: -5%">

                    <nav class="link-effect-2" id="link-effect-2">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-ul" >
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.php" class="effect-3">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="services.php" class="dropdown-toggle effect-3" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="services.php">Services 2</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="services.php">Services 3</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="codes.php">Codes</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="icons.php">Icons</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="services.php">One more separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="jobs.php" class="dropdown-toggle effect-3" data-toggle="dropdown">Jobs<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Walk-ins</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Bpo Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Teaching Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Diploma Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Tech Support</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Finance Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Part time Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Health Care</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Hospitality</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Internships</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Research Jobs</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="jobs.php">Defence Jobs</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                                <li><a href="login.php">Recruiter Updates</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="upload.php">Upload Resume</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="codes.php">Shortcodes</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="events.php" class="effect-3">Events</a></li>

                            <li><a href="professional.php" class="effect-3">Professionals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php" class="effect-3">Contact</a></li>

                            <li  ><a style="margin-top: -5%" href="login.php"> <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='login.php';" style="float: right;background: #23B684;width: 100%;color: white" class="btn btn-block"> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"> </i>   Login</button></a></li>

                        </ul>


                    </nav>
                </div>
                <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
                <!--/.navbar-->
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

JavaScript (JQuery)

```
$('.main-ul li').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
```

I added a `main-ul` on the first `<ul>` so I can easily reference to it and its `<li>` items then I created `.active` in CSS. Now whenever you click on an `<li>` item, a red background is applied to it indicating that it has an `active` class name.

Comment: It's the `e.preventDefault()` that I added that prevents the links from working; just remove it. I only added it because I didn't want to redirect when I was doing an experiment in your code.

Comment: And don't mind clicking the check if this answer helped you :)